# Good Video Training for Programming with POSIX Threads

Tags: linux, multithreading

Working environment LINUX + C & C++.

I am looking for some good training videos for Programming with POSIX® Threads.

Comment: Why video? There are good articles and tutorials you can learn everything from that, the basics aren't complicated. What you *will* need is *a lot of practice*.

Comment: I am not too sure if someone specifically knows about "good training videos for Programming with POSIX® Threads".

Comment: @q0987: Have you tried using `GOOGLE`? there are loads of tutorials about POSIX there, You should search yourself before asking the Q here.

Comment: Als, I did search this before I post the question here.

Comment: yi_H, why video is a good question to ask? simply check tekpub, lynda, pluralsight and you will see why.

Comment: No offence, but I like to watch video for more academic stuff...

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about specific POSIX thread related videos but these are a few places you can get free videos.

http://webcast.berkeley.edu/courses.php

http://www.freevideolectures.com/

http://videolectures.net/

Comment: If you are not sure if those are POSIX videos, then how does this qualify as an answer to the Q, OP asked?

Comment: @Als: Just landing a helping hand. You don't like it?

Comment: And How do you think are you helping, If you are not answering the Q that was asked?

Comment: @Als: By providing a starting point. Sites I mentioned contain good videos. OP can go through the relevant course/page and see if he/she can find something useful. PS: I do not think this discussion is helping in any way. I rest my case.

Comment: Well you are not helping in anyway really, As a personal policy I do not downvote, but I do see some downvotes coming your way through peeps, Wish you luck.